# TCPDF display blank page when using writeHTML

Tags: tcpdf

I have searched every where in stackoverflow but can not find solution to solve my problem.
I have export PDF using TCPDF and using writeHTML to convert HTML to PDF. Some special character in content make my PDF is blank.
Everyone can help.

Comment: Put the code here if you want help...

Comment: This is the code I edited in example file: example_001.php in tcpdf library
`$html = 'Ố Ử Ỏ Ắ À';`
`$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);`

It show blank page

Comment: I just detect that this error still happen when I using `MultiCell`:
`$pdf->MultiCell(55, 5, 'Ố Ử Ỏ Ắ À', 1, 'L', 1, 0, '', '', true);`

Comment: Have you tried adding `<meta charset="utf-8" />` to the `<head>` of your html code ?